# How do I “redraw layers” in Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, graphics, core-graphics

I remember that when I was reading the Apple documentation, it would mention that when you call a function such as `addSubview`, you are adding a “layer of paint,” so to speak, and every time it is called, another layer is overlaid.

This should be an easy question to answer, but I had a hard time thinking of keywords to google for, so please excuse the asking of such a simple question.

**How do I clear the “layers” of a custom `UIView`?**

My situation, as it may be relevant: I have these “user cards” that are displayed on the screen. They are initialized with some user images. The cards stay the same, but I call a method in my custom `UIView` (the card `UIView`) to redraw the images when I want to display a different user. The problem is that some elements of this custom UIView are transparent, and redrawing these images each time builds on that transparency (an obvious problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Core Graphics, what you draw is what gets shown. The painter’s analogy only refers to a single frame. So if you’re using `drawRect`, you just don’t cache the previous drawing.

But I suspect you’re talking about some UIKit stuff where you’ve added subviews or sublayers. This will remove those leftover views if you just want to clear everything:

```
for (UIView *view in customView) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

for (CALayer *layer in customView.layer) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Comment: Your suspision was correct! Great, thank you! This syntax was exactly what I needed to get the code working. The exact code i used was     for (UIView *view in self.myCustomView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's code for clearing UIViews is more or less correct, but if you came here from Google looking for how to clear CLLayers from a view, I was getting a crash when I attempted to fast enumerate `customView.layer` like Ryan has in his example.

When I switched it to regular enumeration, it worked for me. Here's a code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i > yourView.layer.sublayers.count; i++) {
    CALayer *layer = [self.yourView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:i];
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```